# How to attract more well known experts as new users?

Tags: discussion

Comparing this site to other sx sites I noticed that there are very few internationally known coaches, athlets, exercise scientists or sports physicians which contribute to this site.

For example in https://tex.stackexchange.com/ there seems to be a significant part of the leading experts on the field to be active on this site and on https://mathoverflow.net/ there are even [fields medaillists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fields_Medal) writing on it.

So are there any ideas what we could to to attract more expertes to contribute to this site?

Perhaps as a starting point, note that there are many experts who have large blogs, i.e. are addicted to the web in some way but don't seem to contribute to fitness.sx (for example http://bretcontreras.com/ or http://nicktumminello.com/).

Comment: I guess a counter question is how many internationally known coaches or athletes exist?  Then how many have time to spare?

Comment: I think there are too many experts around! Contrary to TeX (basically computer engineering) and Math, fitness is not an exact science but really more like a rather large number of religions... Whatever belief you have, you can always find support for it somewhere from some coach or whatever!

Comment: @TonnyMadsen - On the contrary, while there are many coaches around, that doesn't necessarily make them an expert. I'm thinking more along the lines of attracting researchers, and people creating the theory (Such as Tim Noakes, and his central governor theory on exercise). If we can get the researchers and the leading edge people, the less experienced will start showing up as well.

Comment: Short of contacting some of these bloggers and inviting them over, especially when we see a question that we know they can address, it's like crossing an elephant and a rhino.

Comment: @JohnP I have read through a number of meta studies lately (studies that tries to aggregate the findings of a number of existing studies) and to me it looks like the the majority of the work goes into arbitration between conflicting studies: is HIIT or LSR best for building fitness, how "good or bad" are various types of fats, what are the long term effect of the minimalist movement, which sports goes together when we talk cross-training, etc, etc....

Comment: @TonnyMadsen - If you have questions that could fit, write them up. I'm way behind on reading, so I'd be interested in going through those. Anything we can do to kickstart interest and elevate some of the topical content would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I asked nearly this same question on health, about if professional to professional questions were on topic (Such as a high level EMT asking about strap placements on an extrication device), and I got the below response from Robert Cartaino, a SE community moderator:

> That's awesome: Professionals asking professionals about the questions *they* have in this field.
>
> ***Yes, on topic!***
>
> It would be a bit backward-thinking to exclude the questions that *professionals* would actually have for a site like this… *because they're not "general" enough?*
>
> Think about that.
>
> You would be excluding the interests of the the very people who will (hopefully) drive the **best** content of this site. You would be excluding the people who will make this site "work".
>
> #### Embrace these specialized, long-tailed questions
>
> Many sites have the problem that they strive to become *soooo* generic and applicable to all, that they settle into a Wikipedia-like scope where only uninspired questions that anyone could ask are allowed. And they’ve all been asked 100 times before on every other site on that subject. No thank you.
>
> low applicability to … the general public
>
> To throw in a bit of historical context, this sounds an awful lot like folks looking for things that are *too localized.* "Too localized" once describe questions involving *"…very tiny geographic regions or vanishingly small periods of time",* and it's an out-modded artifact we got rid of a long time ago, *good riddance.* Too localized is no longer a valid reason to flag or close a post.
>
> We should not close questions because "it is too narrow and focused."
>
> If the professionals want to use this site for their specialized interests in this field, you've gotta love it. Failing to embrace these questions with *both* arms would be a big mistake.
>
> *"To attract experts, you need a site where people are asking very interesting and challenging questions, not the basic questions found on every other Q&A site.*
>
> ***Remember, the pro sites WILL attract the enthusiasts, but not the other way around!"***
>
> *— [**Blog Post, Your New Site: Asking the First Questions**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/)*

So, to that end I've started a conversation with Dave Liepmann in the Locker Room and dropped some links to current topics. I think if we can get better questions and invite people we know in the field, I think we can revive what seems to be a lagging site.